# Unable to validate Gmail mail account username or password error

Tags: settings

All the time I get "Username or password incorrect". I have verify again and again this information and it is correct. No mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

This issue you're seeing is likely linked to Google's two-factor authentication. You can either disable two-factor authentication altogether or you can set up an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

If that still doesn't work, you might have to [enable less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).